# Может ли GetWindowRect вернуть координаты больше, чем 65535? WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

Вопрос прост: может ли функция GetWindowRect вернуть координаты, более чем 65535? Мне это нужно знать, чтобы определиться со своим типом координат: int16_t или же какой-либо больший. В документации не нашел ничего по этому вопросу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В справке указано, что ей передается указатель на структуру `RECT`:

```
typedef struct tagRECT {
  LONG left;
  LONG top;
  LONG right;
  LONG bottom;
} RECT, *PRECT, *NPRECT, *LPRECT;
```

В ее определении четко указано: `LONG`. А о нем сказано там же:

> A 32-bit signed integer. The range is -2147483648 through 2147483647 decimal.
> This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:
> `typedef long LONG;`

Вот из этого и советую исходить, не экономя на спичках...

Answer (score 0):

Запустите такую тестилку:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

    int main()
    {
     std::cout<<sizeof(LONG)<<std::endl;
     return 0;
    }
```

. Она выведет размер в байтах, на винде это октеты. Дальше 256 возводим в эту степень и никаких гвоздёв. А если Вам нужен всего лишь гарантированно совместимый тип, то просто используйте тот же самый LONG. А для понимания его возможностей – тестилку, исходник которой приведён выше. Надо же понимать, что в переменную можно самому положить, а что – нет.

Comment: Я не спрашивал про максимально возможный диапазон значений в структуре RECT. Меня интересует, полностью ли этот LONG используется. Функция может возвращать значение, всегда меньше LONG (скорее всего так и есть, а RECT имеет поля типа LONG лишь потому, что используется в других местах, где такой диапазон необходим)

Comment: Серьёзно? Функция возвращает ограниченный диапазон, но зачем-то использует избыточный тип, который необходим где-то ещё? В винде и без этих сложностей слишком много глюков, чтоб ещё специально создавать их потенциальный источник. ГДЕ необходим больший диапазон? В FillRect? Ну очень смешно красить прямоугольник заведомо больше окна. И даже если бы это было так, проще разделить типы. Или уж не накладывать дополнительных явных ограничений на размеры окна. Которые, кстати, ЗАДАЮТСЯ хоть и не целиком ректом, но параметры имеют ту же разрядность.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, Чарлз Петзолдт уже всё сделал за Вас и написал в своей книге, что координаты всей графики ограничены диапазоном от -32 768 до +32 767. Но есть одно но: эта информация могла устареть. Поэтому полагаться надо не на ограничение, а на тип. В чикаго же ограничение проистекало из 16-ти бит, так как это ядро ещё имело хвосты и от всех предыдущих версий винды, и даже от доса.